# Not Greater Than Operator in Swift !>

Tags: swift, logic, operators

All my searches keep turning up irrelevant answers so I was wondering what is the fundamental problem with the question I am asking:

What is the operator in swift that means NOT Greater than " !> " ?
Why doesn't this symbol exist?

edit: Just to clarify: I was trying to make an if statement in Swift where, if the value is not greater than or equal to 0, the value is obviously invalid, but I didn't want to specify a number range. I realized that else would probably catch what I was looking for:

```
if int >= 1 {
        //do something
    }else {
        //number is not an integer greater than 1
        //do something else
    }
```

Comment: Because there is "less or equal", that is the same and it's standard for programming languages.

Comment: @mothy, I was wondering and looking for the same exact thing.   Since I am new to programming, maybe to a expert this might not make sense, but it makes total sense to me that at the very least to be able to state if something is not greater than something else in the form of " !< or !>".  Just like one can use " != " to say that something is not equal to.   I wonder if this is just a swift situation, since I do not know any other programming language, so please pardon my ignorance.
I guess for now, all we have is what has been suggested by others on this thread.
Basically:  !( x > y)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about `<=`? If `x` is not greater than `y`, then `x <= y`. There's no need for a "not greater than" operator when it has the same meaning as "less than or equal to."

Comment: Just to add, I supposed if you want to explicitly state *not greater than* you could use `!(x > y)`

Comment: so for example !(integer > 0) would catch anything that is not zero or less?

Comment: @mothy !(integer > 0) would catch anything that **is** zero or less. !(integer > 0) is the same thing as (integer <= 0)

Comment: The distinction I was hoping to make was if the user put in the letter 'a' or something like that, it would fall into the logic (it was lazy error catching). The <= symbol would not catch the letter 'a' because it would fail the logical test. I use <= and >= all the time. I've read the documentation as much as I could. I hope you see what I was actually looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
if !(int > 1) {
// Do something...
}
```